# Окно отркывается и через несколько секунд закрывается автоматически

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Вот мой код:

```
#include <glad/glad.h> //Обязательно должен быть впереди #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height); 
//Предозначена для ситуации, когда пользователь изменяет размер окна. Автоматически вызывается

void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);

const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;
//Всемилюбимые ненужные константы

int main() {



    glfwInit(); //активируем GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    //если соединить их, то получиться openGL 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    /*Далее мы должны создать объект window, представляющий окно приложения. 
    Присутствие данного объекта требуется для большинства других функций GLFW, 
    т.к. именно через него происходит управление окном нашей программы
    */

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Hello, world", NULL, NULL); 
    //800 - высота, 600 - ширина, "Hello, world" - имя окна, NULL и еще один NULL - пока что нам не нужны
    
    if (window == NULL) { //проверяем на наличие ошибок
        cout << "Failed window file\n";
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); //мы сообщаем GLFW сделать контекст нашего окна основным контекстом в текущем потоке.

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600); 
    /*видимая граница созданного нами окна для пользователя. 
    После этого запуститься само окно. 
    Вся проблема в том, что оно закроется через секунду после запуска
    (Проблема решается на 46 строчке кода)
    */

    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback); 
    /*когда мы изменяем окно, то вызывается эта функция, которая вызывает функцию, 
    вставляя в первый аргумент - WINDOW, а во второй и третий - текущие размеры
    */
    
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) //Пока пользователь не закроет окно WINDOW (glfwWindowShouldClose возвращает true, когда мы закрываем)
    {
        processInput(window);

        // Выполнение рендеринга
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window); //Имеет два буфера, один из которых предозначен для рендеринга, второй - для обработки
        glfwPollEvents(); /*следит за тем, инициируются ли какие-либо события (например, ввод с клавиатуры или перемещение мышки), 
                          обновляет состояние окна и вызывает соответствующие функции (которые мы можем зарегистрировать с помощью callback-методов)*/
}
    
    glfwTerminate(); //очищает все GLFW файлы
    return 0;
}


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow * window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height); 
    //изменяет высоту и ширину
} 

// Обработка всех событий ввода: запрос GLFW о нажатии/отпускании клавиш на клавиатуре в данном кадре и соответствующая обработка данных событий
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}
```

прошу обратить внимание на это:

```
` while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) //Пока пользователь не закроет окно WINDOW (glfwWindowShouldClose возвращает true, когда мы закрываем)
{
    processInput(window);

    // Выполнение рендеринга
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window); //Имеет два буфера, один из которых предозначен для рендеринга, второй - для обработки
    glfwPollEvents(); /*следит за тем, инициируются ли какие-либо события (например, ввод с клавиатуры или перемещение мышки), 
                      обновляет состояние окна и вызывает соответствующие функции (которые мы можем зарегистрировать с помощью callback-методов)*/ }  `
```

В чем проблема? По идее у меня должен открыться черный экран, но у меня отркывается белый и через секунду закрывается.

Comment: Ну а до какой строки выполняется код?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/?view=vs-2019 должно помочь